# How can I getRef() inside a RecyclerView adapter?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

This is the code I tried:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    ChatMessage msg = mMessagesList.get(position);
    holder.messageTextView.setText(msg.getMessage());

    String key = getRef(position).getKey();


    holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });

}
```

But the `getRef()` is red and doesn't work. I think it should be inside a `populateViewHolder` and I don't know how to create one.

Comment: What does the red message say when you hover on it?

Comment: cannot resolve method

Comment: You don't seem to be using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. You can only call getRef if you're using this adapter.

Comment: is there an equivalent i can use ?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation it looks like method doesn't accept parameters.

> getRef()
>
> Used to obtain a reference to the source location for this snapshot.

you can use below code in `onBindViewHolder()`

```
String _key=mMessagesList.get(position).getKey();
```